# Angular 1.x service with separate file

Tags: angularjs, service

I have Angular 1.4 service working in app.js but I want to move this service in a separate file. Can anybody advise me a site explaining how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Heres an example of how you can move your service in a separate file.

app.js:

```
(function(){

    // create main app module
    angular.module('myApp', []);

})();
```

controller.js:

```
(function(){

    angular.module('myApp').controller(MyController, MyController);

    // inject dependencies here
    MyController.$inject = ['MyService'];

    function MyController(MyService) {

        // controller logic

    }

})();
```

service.js:

```
(function(){

    angular.module('myApp').factory('MyService', MyService);

    MyService.$inject = [];

    function MyService() {

        var service = {};

        return service;

    }

})();
```

As for a site with good explanations and best practices, check out the [angular 1.x style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) which has been endorsed by the angular team. Specifically pay attention to [Style Y001](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y001).

Comment: Thank you so much! Will definitely try this out.